# The Java combo-box setSelectedItem malfunctions when the 'System' LookAndFeel is used

Tags: java, jcombobox

I am using the keyTyped listerner to emulate the Windows’ combo-box feature to automatically scroll the combo list-box as the user types into the edit box. It works well when the default cross-platform LookAndFeel is used.
I have discovered that JComboBox.setSelectedItem malfunctions when the LookAndFeel is changed to the system LookAndFeel:

UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

The following code uses the setSelectedItem(OrigTypeface) call toward the end to restore the original text in the edit box.

With the cross-platform LookAndFeel, as the user types ‘abc’, the list box progressively shows the first item matching the typed text in the list box.  However, with the System LookAndFeel, the text in the edit box goes from ‘a’ to ‘b’ to ‘c’, finally showing only the letter ‘c’ in the text-box, and showing list box with the entry staring with the first letter ‘c’.  Effectively, the setSelectedItem is failing, and putting a blank in the text box.

Anyone knows the work-around for this problem?

```
   getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {  
       @Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ev) {
              String OrigTypeface=(String)cb.getEditor().getItem();
              if (OrigTypeface==null) OrigTypeface=""; 
              char CurChar=ev.getKeyChar();
              String typeface=OrigTypeface + CurChar;  character
              typeface=typeface.toLowerCase();
              if (typeface.length()==0 || (int)CurChar==8) return;  // exclude the backspace key

               int i,count=cb.getItemCount();
               for (i=0;i<count;i++) {
                  String item=(String)cb.getItemAt(i);
                  if (item!=null) {
                     item=item.toLowerCase();
                     if (item.startsWith(typeface) && cb.getSelectedIndex()!=i) {

                        int BumpUp=cb.getMaximumRowCount()/2;  // normally list-bolx would position the item the end of the list, so we bump its position to the middle
                        if ((i+BumpUp)<count) cb.setSelectedIndex(i+BumpUp);    
                        cb.setSelectedIndex(i);  // select this item
                        cb.hidePopup();     // hide/show to actually display this item in the scroll list
                        cb.showPopup();

                        cb.setSelectedItem(OrigTypeface);  // put this item back in the edit box since it gets overridden by the above setSelectedIndex call

                        break;
                     } 
                    } 
                 }
              } 
          }               
   });
```

Here is a small java file that you can compile and run to recreate this problem. Simply type 'abc' in two combo-boxes. You will see that the one on the left works properly, but not the one on the right.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.awt.font.*;                    // to get TextAttribute class
import java.awt.geom.*;                    // to get AffilineTransform
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.text.*;                       // to get SimpleDateFormat
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.*;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Media.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.util.prefs.*;
import java.awt.dnd.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComboBoxUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI;

public class demo extends JPanel {
    OurComboBox cb1;
    OurComboBox cb2;
    JLabel lbl1;
    JLabel lbl2;

    public demo() {
        super(new GridLayout(2,2));

        JLabel lbl1=new  JLabel();
        lbl1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 15));
        lbl1.setText("ComboBox using cross-platform L&F");
        add(lbl1);

        JLabel lbl2=new  JLabel();
        lbl2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 15));
        lbl2.setText("ComboBox using System L&F");
        add(lbl2);

        cb1=new OurComboBox();
        cb1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 15));
        cb1.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
        cb1.setEditable(true);  // allow edit box

        AddComboItems(cb1);

        add(cb1);

        // change to System LookAndFeel temporarily
        try {UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());} 
        catch (Exception ex) {}

        cb2=new OurComboBox();
        cb2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 15));
        cb2.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
        cb2.setEditable(true);  // allow edit box
        AddComboItems(cb2);
        add(cb2);

        // rever back LookAndFeel
        try {UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName()); }
        catch (Exception ex) {}

    }

    // add items to the combo-box
    void AddComboItems(OurComboBox cb) {
       for (int i=0;i<20;i++) cb.addItem("a"+((Integer)i).toString());
       for (int i=0;i<20;i++) cb.addItem("ab"+((Integer)i).toString());
       for (int i=0;i<20;i++) cb.addItem("abc"+((Integer)i).toString());
       for (int i=0;i<20;i++) cb.addItem("bc"+((Integer)i).toString());
    } 

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add content to the window.
        frame.add(new demo());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
            UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
            createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

 class OurComboBox extends JComboBox {
    public boolean locked;
    public OurComboBox cb;

    OurComboBox() {
       cb=this;  // save so it can be accessed inside the key listerner below

       getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {  // add key listenr to the editor component
           @Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ev) {
               String OrigTypeface=(String)cb.getEditor().getItem();
               if (OrigTypeface==null) OrigTypeface="";  // 20150313  
               char CurChar=ev.getKeyChar();
               String typeface=OrigTypeface + CurChar;  // getItem() returns the prviously typed text, getKeyChar()) returns the latest character
               typeface=typeface.toLowerCase();
               if (typeface.length()==0 || (int)CurChar==8) return;  // exclude the backspace key

               if ((int)CurChar==0xa) return;    // just return for now
               else {     // scroll the combo-box to show the currently typed typefacee
                  int i,count=cb.getItemCount();
                  for (i=0;i<count;i++) {
                     String item=(String)cb.getItemAt(i);
                     if (item!=null) {
                        item=item.toLowerCase();
                        if (item.startsWith(typeface) && cb.getSelectedIndex()!=i) {
                           cb.locked=true;  // don't process item state changed for this change

                           if ((i+cb.getMaximumRowCount()/2)<count) cb.setSelectedIndex(i+cb.getMaximumRowCount()/2);  // try to move the actual index in the middle because java by default shows the selected index at the bottom  
                           cb.setSelectedIndex(i);  // select this item
                           cb.hidePopup();     // hide/show to actually display this item in the scroll list
                           cb.showPopup();

                           cb.setSelectedItem(OrigTypeface);  // put this item back in the edit box
                           cb.locked=false;

                           break;
                        } 
                     } 
                  }
               } 
           }
       });
    } 

 }
```

Comment: `I am using the keyTyped listerner` - Don't. You should be using a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html). `However, with the System LookAndFeel,` - which in your case is? Is the problem a platform bug or a coding bug. Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem so the code can be tested on different platforms. `OrigTypeface, CurChar` variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Most are correct. Be consistent!!!

Comment: I tried DocumentListener and it was worse.  The setSelectedIndex call above changes the content of the text-edit area and the process goes in a loop.  I also tried running the code within SwingUtilities.InvokeLater.  For either case it does not make a difference.  I am using the keyTyped listener since it gets invoke only by a keyboard input (unlike DocumentListener).

Comment: `I am using the keyTyped listener since...` makes sense, but you still haven't posted a SSCCE, so we are no closer to being able to help.

Comment: I have not looked into what all involves in SSCCE, but here is very quick & simple java example.  You can download it from:  www.subsystems.com/temp/demo.java.  It includes two combo-boxes, one with the default L&F, and the other with the System L&F. You can test by typing 'abc' in the edit areas.  I have so far recreated this problem under Java 7.x and 8.x on Windows OS. I am very interested in your thoughts on the bug, but not the coding style.  I'm way past that topic.

Comment: Post your code in the forum with your question.

Comment: Are you able to download and run the demo.java program to recreate the problem?

Comment: The code isn't posted in the forum so no I can't copy it. And I'll be going to bed soon so I won't be able to look at it tonight. Another day gone by.  All the information we need to solve the problem should be posted in the forum so we don't have to keep asking for information. That is how you get a better answer faster.